# How do you use uDigs mapviewer in a separate Eclipse RCP program

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, gis

uDig claims that you can use is it as a plug-in to an existing RCP application, what I would like to do is have my own view with a map backed by GeoServer that I can add my own layers and points to without having to use uDigs SDK.

Even though the claim is there, there doesn't seem to be any documentation to back it up, so how do you do it?

It seems to me that uDig is really the only option out there for rich client GIS software and I don't like the idea of having to use their application framework to gain access to it.

Your help would be appreciated. x

Comment: Did you find a solution, i have the same problem. I do not find a tutorial how to integrate uDig as an Plugin in my own RCP Application.

Comment: No sorry. I ended up building something from scratch using a very basic SWT map component.

Comment: I ended using SWT Browser and OpenLayers as Javascript Framework xD